# Where should environment variables be set for Jenkins

Tags: shell, environment-variables, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to automate application builds using Maven on Linux.

Where should I set environment variables such as `$JAVA_HOME` and append items to `$PATH` so that they are available to Jenkins?

I have tried a few different places and had no success. I'm not certain on what sort of shell Jenkins uses, whether its a login/non-login, interactive or non-interactive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the perfect scenario for a Global Tool Configuration.  From the Jenkins home page, Click *Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration*.  If you have a default installation, this page will let you add multiple configurations for installing Maven on your build servers.

[image: Global Tool Configuration for Maven]

Once you've configured the tools, you can use them in your jobs by adding  "Invoke Top Level Maven Targets" build steps.  If you are using specific slaves/nodes for each job, you can pick the Maven that should be installed on each server.  Then when the jobs run, Jenkins will manage the installation for you automatically.

[image: "Invoke Top Level Maven Targets" Build Step]

Specifically for pipelines, there's the [Pipeline Maven Integration plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven).  I haven't used it but from the docs it looks like it should be able to do what you're asking:

> Provides Maven integration with Pipeline Plugin by using the withMaven
>   step, which configures a maven environment to use within a pipeline
>   job by calling sh mvn or bat mvn.

And this blog post, [Declarative Pipeline for Maven Projects](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/#declarative-pipeline-for-maven-projects), give a good example of configuring Jenkins to run a pipeline with Maven.

Comment: I ended up using this approach. However please note that the global tools is just that - global. To vary by agent you must override in the agent configuration.

Comment: @MarkW do you mind selecting this as the approach you used?

Answer (score 7):

This question was already asked over at Stack Overflow and you may want to look at the answers there: [How to set environment variables in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins)

Global, static environment variables can be set for any Jenkins installation in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties > Environment Variables.

Environment variables can be set per-executor in the executor settings. There's a tickbox for "environment variables" and when it is ticked, the environment variable configuration is exposed.

Environment variables can also be set per-job:

- If you are using [Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), use the [`withEnv`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables) step.
- If you are using old-style Freestyle jobs, use the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I am using pipelines, and that will probably work. However paths vary by node environment. I have several, and I'd rather not have several conditional statements in the pipeline. It makes it quite brittle.

Comment: @MarkW environment variables can be set per-executor in the executor settings.  There's a tickbox for "environment variables" and when it is ticked, the environment variable configuration is exposed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using configuration-as-code to configure the Jenkins master instance, you can use `globalNodeProperties` as shown at https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/d9171d086fbbf92cb5807da2dd12d6fc43df7a6b/demos/jenkins/jenkins.yaml#L7-L11:

```
globalNodeProperties:
    - envVars:
        env:
          - key: FOO
            value: BAR
```